# Como passa um valor de uma Activity para um Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou tentando instanciar um método que retorna um valor do tipo int em um Fragmento, mas quando mostro o valor na tela do dispositivo o TextView mostra isso: null.

Código do Fragment:

```
   public View onCreateView(/*@NonNull*/ LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        Valor valor = new Valor();

        // TXTVIDAS
        TextView vidas = view.findViewById(R.id.txtVidas);
        vidas.setText(String.valueOf("fgdfhgd" + valor.getVidas()));

        // Botão começar
        Button btncomecar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btncomecar);
        btncomecar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MundosActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
```

Eu testei e o método retorna um valor diferente de null:

```
D/Vidas encotradas: 4
```

Ou seja, deveria aparecer um quatro em vez de "null".

Answer (score 1):

Vou te passar o método que é pra passar como argumento. Existem outros métodos de comunicação por meio de [Listener](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating) ou [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

Enfim, crie um novo fragmento já com o construtor `newInstance()` pronto. Para isso, vá em:

> > File > New > Fragment > Fragment(Blank)

Já é um template que cria um fragmento e um layout novo, você pode nomear ele.

Existe nele o construtor chamado `newInstance(String param1, String param2)`

Altere e deixe da seguinte maneira:

```
//nome do seu fragment
public static MeuFragmento newInstance(int param1) {
    MeuFragmento fragment = new MeuFragmento ();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

**No `onCreate()` do fragment deixe:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
    }
}
```

**No método `onCreateView()`, repare que passo o valor do parametro no textview:**

```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meu_fragmento, container, false);

        // TXTVIDAS
        TextView vidas = view.findViewById(R.id.txtVidas);

        vidas.setText(String.valueOf("fgdfhgd" + mParam1));

        // Botão começar
        Button btncomecar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btncomecar);
        btncomecar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MundosActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Agora na sua Activity onde inicializa e chama o fragmento ao invés de usar:

```
Fragment meuFragmento = new MeuFragmento();
```

use:

```
Fragment meuFragmento = MeuFragmento.newInstance(valor.getVidas());
```

Espero que te ajude. Abraço!

Comment: Eu conseguir resolver o problema de outra maneira, mas obrigado pela ajuda!